# Tkinter auto-trigger callback continuously

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple tkinter callback that scrubs forward through a video when a key is pressed or held down.

```
root.bind('<Right>', callback_scrubFwd)
root.mainloop()
```

This plays back the video very nicely. How can I trigger this callback to be called continuously, which is what happens when the key is held down by the user, only automatically? I've tried ordinary `while` loops or nested/timed function calls but these lock up the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a function to run continuously, at the end of the function you can call `after` to put another invocation of the callback on the event queue:

```
def callback_scrubFwd():
    <your code here>
    root.after(1000, callback_scrubFwd)
```

If you want to be able to stop the auto-repeat you can add a flag that you check for each time it is called:

```
def callback_scrubFwd():
    <your code here>
    if do_autorepeat:
        root.after(1000, callback_scrubFwd)
```